# Trouble printing the highest value read from a file

Tags: python

So I have created a quiz. I have saved the users quiz in a text file using python. 
I have figured out how to allow a teacher to view the users names in alphabetical order with their score from the text file.

This is what my code looks like so far..

```
def alpha():
  b = open("Class X.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted (fo): 
      print(x)
def beta():
  b = open("Class Y.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)
def charlie():
  b = open("Class Z.txt" , "r")
  fo = b.readlines()
  for x in sorted(fo):
      print(x)
option = input("Do you want to review the scores in/from: A)Alphabetical order with highest score. 

if option == "A":
  if Class == "X":
    alpha()

  elif Class == "Y":
    beta()

  elif Class == "Z":
    charlie()`
```

What I have been trying to do is print all the users names in alphabetical order from a text file, which I have been successful with. However, I have been having great trouble in trying to print the highest score of each user along side their name instead of any of their scores.

My text file looks like this.

```
Joe:2 
Jale:4 
Laurence:1 
Harry:2 
Nakita:2
```

I was wondering whether anyone could help me figure out how to include just the highest score with the users name in alphabetical order like I have done, from the textfile which has been set out like how it it shown above. 
I have also used the version Python 3.3.2.

Comment: how does your text file look

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

lines = [line.strip().split(':') for line in open('results.txt')]


for each in lines:
    each[1] = int(each[1])
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

for each in lines:
    print each[0],':',each[1]
```

Output:

```
Laurence : 1
Joe : 2
Harry : 2
Nakita : 2
Jale : 4
```

This print out the list of names sorted according to ascending order of the scores. If you want it alphabetically use `(key=itemgetter(0))`